# For proving $\phi$ (totient) is multiplicative how can I guarantee my function is well-defined?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, chinese-remainder-theorem

My professor approved my approach to proving that $\phi$ is multiplicative using a counting argument and a bijection. Since we do not cover rings I could not take the easier and more general approach using $\mathbb{Z_n}$ (mostly because I have yet to study those topics). He mentioned my proof is fine for this class but he said if I wanted to be extra pedantic I should mention why the function I introduced is well defined.

Here is my proof:

We claim that $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\cdot\phi(n)$, when $\gcd(m,n)=1$. To show this is true we will apply a counting argument. The goal is to construct two sets of integers, one that has $\phi(mn)$ elements and the other $\phi(m)\phi(n)$ elements. If we can establish a bijection between the sets then we will have shown that
$\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

We begin by constructing the set $Z_1$ defined as $$Z_1=\{a\mid1\leq a\leq mn\textrm{ and } \gcd(a,mn)=1\}$$ That is $Z_1$ contains all the positive values less than or equal to $mn$ and coprime to $mn$. By definition the size of this set is $\phi(mn)$. Also let us define the set $Z_2$ as
$$ Z_2=\{(b,c)\mid1\leq b\leq m\textrm{ and }\gcd(b,m)=1
    \textrm{ and }1\leq c\leq n\textrm{ and }\gcd(c,n)=1\}$$
We choose the first value of the ordered pair namely $b$ which can be done in $\phi(m)$ ways. Then for the second value of the ordered pair namely $c$ which can be done in $\phi(n)$ ways. Then by definition of cardinality the total number of ordered pairs that can be constructed in $Z_2$ is the product of the two values, that is $\phi(m)\phi(n)$ ways. To show the sets $Z_1,Z_2$ are the same cardinality we will define a bijection $f: Z_1\rightarrow Z_2$. for each $a\in Z_1$ define $f(a)=(b,c)$ where $(b,c)\in Z_2$, with $b\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv a\pmod{n}$. To see that $f$ is injective, let $f(a)=f(b)$, then by definition we have $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$. Then we know by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $a\equiv b\pmod{mn}$. Since $a,b\in Z_1$ it follows that $a=b$. To show $f$ is surjective consider the congruences $x\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv c\pmod{n}$. Again by the chinese remainder theorem these two congruences have a simultaneous solution $a$ that is unique modulo $mn$. That is we have found an $a$ such that $f(a)=(b,c)$. This completes the proof and the statement that $\phi$ is multiplicative is true.

I am unsure by what he means by well-defined as I thought the Chinese remainder theorem gives us that 1-to-1 correspondence.

Comment: I think he means when you define $f(a)=(b,c)$ you should explain why there is only one pair $(b,c)$ that satisfies the requirements.  That's what well-defined means.  There's one and only one object that fulfills the requirements.  Of course, the Chinese remainder theorem guarantees that $f$ is well-defined.  If $f$ weren't well-defined, your instructor would not have said the proof was fine for your class, or any other.  It's just that you didn't mention well-definition.

Comment: To expand on that,  a well defined function is one that maps every element in the domain to a unique element of the codomain.  So you have to show #1:  the pair (b,c) exists for every a and #2: the pair is unique.  Anytime you assert a function by a rule that isn't crystal clear on its face that it is well defined, you need to justify it, usually it is fast (Via CRT)

Comment: I see! So even when CRT is mentioned I still need to voice the implication that $f(a)=(b,c)$ is going to be well defined by CRT? Or is there something I am failing to show? As in I thought the steps showing the injection and surjection do satisfy those requirements.